# Editing your model in json while keeping a reference to the model

Tags: json, sapui5

What is the recommended way to modify data in the model without having to set a new model to the view afterwards again?

I have a function where I need to calculate something on the client side and change this in my model:

```
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(this.getView().getModel().getJSON());
$.each(parsedJSON['UserData']['clockHistory'], function(idx, obj) {
// do some stuff to clockHistory
});
this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/UserData/clockHistory", clockHistory);
```

The getModel().getJSON() only returns a JSON string, but not a JSON object that can be used in javascript.

Comment: getModel.getData() returns the JSON object

Comment: You are correct sir. I do get the json object, but after modifying it the model is not updated (with setProperty it is).

Comment: you also need to call oModel.refresh() to update

Comment: Works great! Combine your both comments in an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To get `JSON` object of `JSONModel`, call `this.getView().getModel().getData()`
2. To refresh the data update, call `oModel.refresh()`

Answer (score 2):

You can even skip the `oModel.refresh()` part, if you use `this.getView().getModel.getProperty("/UserData/clockHistory/")` to get the desired value from the model.
getProperty() will return a object. Objects are created by reference. So any changes to the new object will update the model:

```js
var object = yourModel.getProperty("/PATH/TO/PROPERTY");

object = "new Value";  //this will update the model as well!
```

If you are using data binding to a control, UI5 will inform the control about the changes.